# Configuration for specific Caffeine Caches in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-cache, caffeine

We need to implement several methods that have different caching times. Each method is annotated with `@Cacheable` and our current solution includes multiple `CacheManager` that are set in a `CachingConfigurerSupport`.

```
public class CachingConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaffeine(Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    return cacheManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public CacheManager anotherCache() {
    CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaffeine(Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
    return cacheManager;
  }
}
```

The `@Cacheable` annotation then included the cacheManager:
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "someCache", cacheManager = "anotherCache")

Basically that's fine but is also errorprune if you forget the `cacheManager` parameter etc.

So I currently try to find a better solution but as far as I can see, there is currently no general accepted way to go.

Imho the main advantage of the `CaffeineCacheManager` compared to e.g. `SimpleCacheManager` is the possibility to define a base configuration and then initialize additional caches lazily. But wouldn't it be great if you are able to set additional caches which are never reinitialized?

Those caches must be used preferentially and created in the `CachingConfigurerSupport`.

Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't this solve the problem that has already been discussed in several threads in different forms?

Comment: You might want to chime in on this [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1506). The integration was a direct port of the prior Guava version.

Comment: Also see this [answer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7235#issuecomment-256587531) - “expose individual caches as @Beans and Spring Boot will automatically detect that and create a CacheManager for you”

Comment: Thanks @Ben I hoped that you would find this question ;) exposing individual caches as Beans is OK but not really configurable. I'll try to help in the PR if possible

Comment: New PR created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1932

Answer (score 2):

Recently I decided to turn my [initial PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1506) into a separate [tiny project](https://github.com/stepio/coffee-boots).

To start using it just add the latest dependency from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.stepio.coffee-boots</groupId>
    <artifactId>coffee-boots</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Format of properties is the following:

```
coffee-boots.cache.spec.myCache=maximumSize=100000,expireAfterWrite=1m
```

If no specific configuration is defined, `CacheManager` defaults to Spring's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way without any thrid-party lib:

```
spring.cache.type=caffeine
# default spec (optional)
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=250,expireAfterWrite=15m
# specific specs (also optional)
caffeine.specs.places=maximumSize=1000,expireAfterWrite=1h
```

Register custom caches:

```
applicationContext.registerBean { context ->
    CacheManagerCustomizer<CaffeineCacheManager> { cacheManager ->
        for (spec in Binder.get(context.environment).bindOrCreate("caffeine.specs", HashMap::class.java)) {
            cacheManager.registerCustomCache(spec.key.toString(), Caffeine.from(spec.value.toString()).build())
        }
    }
}
```